# Identifying a thin, black, worm-like creature with a hammer-shaped head

Tags: species-identification

I came across the creature shown in the photo below yesterday evening while walking the dogs. At first, I thought it was an earthworm, but a flashlight revealed it to be something I had never seen before.

[image]

It is approximately 12 inches (300 mm) in length and about 1/3 of an inch (10 mm) in diameter at its maximum. It is pitch black and very shiny—like piano black. It moves very slowly, using a snake-like motion. It had a very strange head, like a hammerhead shark.

I live in Durban, South Africa, if that helps to narrow down the possibilities.

Can anyone help in identifying this creature?

Comment: Was it moving (like most animals, including earthworm) do? Also, is it climbing up the wall? or it is floor?

Comment: Sorry, the picture is of concrete paving and yes it was moving, but very slowly, not as slow as a slug, more like a very lazy snake movement

Comment: Why sorry? Both the photograph and descriptions are good enough to your effort. It was just a suggestion to improve the description. You could add this details, that would make the creature less-weird when I'll try to imagine it from the photograph.

Comment: Hi Always confused, Your suggestions are most welcome, it is the first time I am using this forum and if I came across to strongly, please excuse me, it was not intended. Using your suggestions as to what it could be, I googled "hammerhead worm" and there is an identical picture and it is called a hammerhead slug. Very interesting animal / creature. Regards,..Graham

Comment: Careful, they might be deadly :) . https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=XW8F1boWgv0

Comment: @GrahamMattsson "about 3 inches (10 mm) ". heh?? :)

Comment: @bic:  I would guess that is 0.3 inches, 10 mm, from the photo and the quoted length.

Answer (score 17):

Hmm, I don't believe I have ever seen that before, but it [looks](http://www.tsusinvasives.org/home/database/bipalium-kewense)  like a [Hammerhead Worm (Bipalium kewense)](https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bipalium).

Comment: Fascinating. Once of your links documents this creature as being an invasive species in Texas, although I have never come across it. It's particularly interesting that it produces tetrodotoxin, probably as an aid to killing its earthworm prey.

Comment: Fascinating indeed. [Here](https://peerj.com/articles/297/) is a very interesting read about Platydemus manokwari, an invasive flatworm from new Guinea.

Comment: Sorry I meant to say that on your link to Bipalium kewense, the hammerhead worm looks very similar to the one I saw in my garden crossing the paving, but was totally shiny black and round in girth, I meant to say 3/8" and not 3 inches in diameter (10mm).

Comment: I am not sure if I should destroy it the next time I see it or should I seek advice locally, maybe capture it in a bottle.

Comment: I think this still fits your description. It can't be shown in the linked pictures, but it [is shiny black](https://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/commons/c/c4/Bipalium_kewense.jpg)

Comment: If this completely answers your question consider accepting it. It  marks the question as resolved. @GrahamMattsson

Comment: "Slug" feels like a misleading term, since that is normally a common name for some molluscs (snails), while this is  Platyhelminth (flatworm)

Comment: @fileunderwater You are right, my bad...

Comment: Thank you for your interesting comments, another misleading term is flatworm as it is actually round.

Answer (score 1):

That looks like a predatory land flatworm.  They eat snails and worms.  I think they are native to New Zealand, but have been introduced to many parts of the US through ornamental plants.

https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Geoplanidae

Comment: The OP pretty clearly states the photograph was taken in Durban, South Africa. Additionally, none of the images in your Wikipedia link are similar to the one provided.

Comment: Missed the location.  I see that now.  In the Wikipedia article if you scroll down and look at the "variety" picture there is one that is pretty close except for it has a stripe down the back.  Incidentally, I've seen black ones that look exactly like the one pictured in OP's original question several times in Southern California.  I used to see the striped one like in the wikipedia picture frequently in Central Texas.

Comment: Hi Cowan, There is a similar picture on the subject of Hammerhead worm shown in Google images. I was very fascinated as I have never seen this before.