# How does this small brown crescent-headed land planarian(?) "look around" and sense its envirnoment?

Tags: species-identification, behaviour, sensation

This 2-3 cm long, thin brown worm with a wide "anchor" or hammer or crescent shaped head was seen in northern Taiwan slowly moving along a damp tile outdoor surface. It moved by contraction/extension *and regularly lifted its head* appearing to explore its environment, as if to say "where should I go next"?

Comments suggest that this is a [land planarian](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Geoplanidae).

**Question:** Is it possible to confirm that this is a land planarian **and to understand what sensory organs it has on its head** in order to "look around" and decide where to go next?

[image]

[image]

Comment: Related: https://biology.stackexchange.com/q/55054/16866

Comment: @theforestecologist yes, it does indeed look like a [land planarian](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bipalium) and the hammer-shaped head was my first clue, thanks! (see also [here](https://archive.org/stream/zoologischeergeb01webe#page/n514/mode/1up) from [here](https://commons.wikimedia.org/wiki/File:Land_planarians.jpg)) So all that's left now is the part about how it senses its environment.

Comment: Edited to reinforce that **this is not a duplicate because what's still asked here is the part about how it senses the environment**

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Given that "hammerhead worms" are Bipaliinae, I expect you can find your species from [this bibliography](http://planarian.net/kswp/45/taiwan.pdf)<sup>1</sup>.  *Bipalium* or *Diversibipalium ruteofulvum* and cosmopolitan *Bipalium kewense* are mentioned, but I did not find images of these species online just now.

A paper about the sense organs of *B. kewense* [(Abdel-Haleem, 2014)](https://pdfs.semanticscholar.org/cc7c/24e6d3fb8c8f3961a462ee6454b10c1eb7e2.pdf) mentions many small pigment cup eyespots, as well as papillae and pits that may be chemosensory in nature.

---

<sup>1</sup>Kawakatsu et al. 2004 *An Annotated Bibliography of Taiwan Land Planarians, with Lists of Linked Papers on This Animal Group*

Comment: Thanks for your answer! The historical bibliography is intriguing, and also provides a historical view to the colonial rule period.